# Force a tkinter interface to reload after configuration changed

Tags: python, tkinter, configparser

I have added the option to translate an application into English and Spanish through a menu and a submenu with "checkbutton". For the translations I have used configparser
The configuration is saved in an ini file that is modified every time we select one option or another. I'm trying to get the translation of the program to load without having to run the program again.

Here is the part of the code I'm refering:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Menu
import configparser

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.Configuration = configparser.ConfigParser()
        self.Configuration.read("config.ini")       

        self.lang_var = tk.StringVar(value=self.Configuration["default"]["language"])

        self.lang_dict = configparser.ConfigParser()
        self.lang_dict.read("language.ini", encoding='utf-8')

        self.strings = self.lang_dict[(self.Configuration["default"]["language"])]

        #translation example
        self.title(self.strings["title"])   

        menubar = Menu(self)
        self['menu'] = menubar
        helpmenu = Menu(menubar)
        language = Menu(menubar)
        menubar.add_cascade(label=self.strings["help"], menu=helpmenu)
        helpmenu.add_cascade(label=self.strings["language"],menu=language)
        language.add_checkbutton(label='English', variable=self.lang_var, onvalue="en", offvalue="es", command=self.refresh_interface)
        language.add_checkbutton(label='Castellano', variable=self.lang_var, onvalue="es", offvalue="es", command=self.refresh_interface)

    def refresh_interface(self):
        self.Configuration["default"]["language"] = self.lang_var.get()
        with open('config.ini', 'w') as configfile:
            self.Configuration.write(configfile)
        self.destroy()
        self.__init__()     

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

config.ini:

```
[default]
language = es
```

language.ini:

```
[en]
help = Help
language = Language
title = Stackoverflow Example
[es]
help = Ayuda
language = Idioma
title = Ejemplo para Stackoverflow
```

I am trying to reload the tkinter interface so that the translation of the program changes in real time.

I got it to work by destroying the program and restarting it. I've tried the tk.update and tk.update_idletasks() methods but they didn't work for me.

```
#Previous part of code remains the same
    def refresh_interface(self):
        self.Configuration["default"]["language"] = self.lang_var.get()
        with open('config.ini', 'w') as configfile:
            self.Configuration.write(configfile)
        self.update()
        #also self.update_idletasks()
```

What I would like to know is if there is a more elegant way to reload the interface instead of destroying and starting.

Comment: It worked for me.  Change `self.title(self.strings["title"])` to `self.title("title")`

Comment: You don't needed this `tk.update()` and `tk.update_idletasks()`. I usually do IRC chat

Comment: Hi @toyotaSupra, I forgot to add the translation for the title in language.ini, I just corrected. 
What I want to know is, if there is another way to force the app interface to reload after the language selection is changed instead of the current I'm using.